# Alternating line-break for two div-containers in CSS

Tags: html, css, line-breaks

If I have some text in a div-container I‘ll get an automatic line-break depending on the size of the container. I would like to have this automatic line-break for two div-containers but in alternating order. On the picture you can see what I would like to get according to the html-code. I do not focus on the alternating colour. I marked the background coloured that it is better understandable what I'm looking for.

As I want to have it for very long and different content, I don’t want to do it by hand with many containers. Another problem would be the inflexibility when I do it this way. I want it to work with a flexible surrounding container size.

Is there a way to implement that with CSS or in any other way?

[image: Here you find a picture of the output what I would like to get]

```
<div id="surrounding_container">
  <div id="box1">
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eaque quasi doloum ..  
  </div>
  <div id="box2">
    3.1415926535 8979323846 2643383279 5028841971 69399375105820974944 5923078164 0628620899 …     
  </div>
</div>
```

### I am trying to explain the problem in more detail.

[image: in this picture]

Comment: Welcome! SO is not a way to make people write the request that you want. Please add a little code snippet to see what you have tried so far.

Comment: Can you maybe explain the alternating order a bit more?

Comment: Thank you johannchopin. The problem is that I don't have a clue how to solve this problem, that means I have tried nothing yet.

Comment: Christian, I tried to explain it in more detail.

Comment: the text contents start to flow on alternating lines?  Why do you want something like this?

Comment: This could be useful for viewing translated text, but only if the original and translated text are close to a 1-to-1 word translation.

Comment: this really isn't "alternating linebreaks..." this is about alternating content...

Comment: @Brett DeWoody: Yeah, this is exactly the problem. I believe you could achieve that in ReactJS's JSX by using some kind of framework that is able to translate and compare text for you. The framework definitely needs to be able to understand the text so it can line break at the right spot. I don't know if any framework like that exists but if it does it would be my #1 choice.

Comment: @nopole I am very thankful for your post. Because I thought about a short headline that clearly describes the problem, yesterday. But I just didn't find anything suitable for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's probably a ton of edge cases that need to be tested here, but here's one approach. Use 2 `<p>` tags with line-heights about 2x their normal value. Position the 2nd `<p>` absolutely so it's positioned within the space between the lines of 1st `<p>`. As the lines of each `<p>` wrap they will be offset from each other.

One of the obvious edge cases is when the text of the 2 `<p>` tags is drastically different - the longer `<p>` will have lots of extra lines of widely-spaced text. So this really only works when the 2 `<p>` elements have similar lengths of text.

```css
html {
  font-size: 16px;
}

div {
  position: relative;
}

p {
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 3rem;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  color: red;
}

p:nth-child(2) {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1.5rem;
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for that useful solution and the quick answer. The output is exactly what I want to have and it works great.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a complete solution and honestly your request got me pensive but I believe the dd-Tag and wbr-tag might be well-suited for this task. Even though it does not always work but...

```
<div>
            <dd>depending on the line above. <wbr>Something like a translation to this line.</dd>
            <dd>abhängig von der Zeile darüber. <wbr>So etwas wie eine Übersetzung zu dieser Zeile<dd>
</div>
```

...combined/experimented with Brett DeWoody's solution and CSS skills it should do the job for you. Perhaps using an unordered list might also work for you:

```
<ul>
  <li class="tranlsationEng">depending on the line above. <wbr>Something like a translation to this line.</li>
  <li class="translationGer">abhängig von der Zeile darüber. <wbr>So etwas wie eine Übersetzung zu dieser Zeile</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick Answer. I don't get an alternating order of lines by this solution. When I understood right, with the <wbr>-tag I can specify where the browser should do a line Break. If you are interested in the solution you should have a look at the answer of Brett DeWoody.